# Online LaTeX syntax highlighter

Tags: editors, online

I am looking for a online LaTeX editor with syntax highlighting that i can plug into my webpage (Something like the CKEditor for html) but i have not been able to find one. Does anyone know about such an online editor? I am looking for a free version :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Free version as used in stackoverflow   http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/. You will need to do some hacking yourself or outsource to someone to fully integrate with your website. For an absolute gem of a code editor see http://codemirror.net/

Answer (score 2):

At the online course at [learnlatex.org](https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-10) we are using the [ACE](https://ace.c9.io/) editor and which includes some support for latex highlighting out of the box.